# Contraction Hierarchies minimal distance proof

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I am trying to implement "Contraction Hierarchies" algorithm and reading the [white paper](https://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/contract.pdf) and watching [video lectures [6,7]](https://ad-wiki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/EfficientRoutePlanningSS2012). But still I can't understand proof for the following lemma:

> Lemma 1. $d(s, t) = min(d(s, v) + d(v, t) : v $ is settled in both
> searches $)$.
>
> Proof. We only give a proof outline for self-containedness
> since the CH-query is a special case of the HNR-query for which a
> detailed yet simple correctness proof is given in [4]. In particular,
> here we only consider the case where shortest paths are unique.
>
> Let $v$ denote the largest node on the shortest path $P$ from $s$ to $t$. We first claim that the sequence of prefix maxima of $P$ forms the shortest path from $s$ to $v$ in the upward graph $G↑$. If $s = v$ there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, consider any pair $(u, w)$ of subsequent prefix maxima in $P$ and the overlay graph $G′ = (u..n, E′)$ existing at some point during contraction. Since the shortest path from $u$ to $w$ uses only interior nodes smaller than $u$, and by definition of the properties of an overlay graph, $(u, w) ∈ E′$ and $c(u, w) = d(u, w)$. Moreover, $u < w$ and hence $(u,w) ∈ G↑$. Analogously, the sequence of suffix maxima of $P$ forms the shortest path from $v$ to $t$ in the downward graph.
>
> [4]  Schultes, D., Sanders, P.: Dynamic highway-node routing. In: Demetrescu, C. (ed.)
> WEA 2007. LNCS, vol. 4525, pp. 66–79. Springer, Heidelberg (2007)

What I currently understood: There is a path $P$ from $s$ to $t$ and there is a node $v$ in it, with the highest importance order. The path from $s$ to $v$ consists from the prefix maxima, i.e. $s = v_0 \to v_1 \to v_2, ... , v_k = v$. Where $v_i-1 < v_i$ and $v_{i-1} \to v_i$ uses only nodes $< v_{i-1}$:

[image: This drawing is from lecture slides]

The rest of the proof is unclear. Mostly the overlay graph $G'$

Comment: Can you identify the first statement in the proof that is not clear to you?

Comment: 1. "consider any pair (,) of subsequent prefix maxima in  and the overlay graph ′=(..,′) existing at some point during contraction." - Why do we need an overlay graph if we already have a shortest path from s to v ?

2. "Since the shortest path from  to  uses only interior nodes smaller than , and by definition of the properties of an overlay graph, (,)∈′ and (,)=(,)." - Well, it is clear why u to w uses only interior nodes smaller than u, but what does the next statement prove ?